# Delete duplicated elements in a list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I've appreciate some helping hand over here. I'm trying to construct a procedure which delete duplicated elements in a list. This part is easy. But then I also want to delete duplicated elements (which may also be lists) and if it is a list the duplicated elements in that list should also be deleted, e.g (make-set (list 1 2 3 2 (list 1 3 2 4 3 4) (list 1 3 2 4 3 4))) should be '(1 3 2 (1 2 3 4)) but in our case it becomes '(1 3 2 2 3 4). Which isn't what we want. What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

```
;; Checks if an element x appears in a list (set)
(define (element-of-set? x set)
  (cond (( null? set) false)
        ((equal? x (car set)) true)
        (else (element-of-set? x (cdr set)))))

;; Delete duplicated elements of a list (set)
(define make-set
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((if (list? (car lst))
               (cond ((null? (car lst))
                      '()
                      )
                     ((element-of-set? (caar lst) (car lst)) (make-set (cdar lst))
                                                              )
                     (else (cons (caar lst) (make-set cadr lst))))
               (cond ((element-of-set? (car lst) (cdr lst)) (make-set (cdr lst)))
                     (else (cons (car lst) (make-set (cdr lst))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want to build a function `make-set` that manages a generalized, untyped concept of set (that is a set that can contain either numbers or recursively other sets), the definition is quite complex. Here is my try.

```
;; check if x is contained in set
(define (contained? x set)
  (cond ((null? set) false)
        ((my-equal? x (car set)) true)
        (else (contained? x (cdr set)))))

;; check if all the elements of set1 are contained in set2
(define (set-contained? set1 set2)
  (cond ((null? set1) true)
        ((null? set2) false)
        (else (and (contained? (car set1) set2)
                   (set-contained? (cdr set1) set2)))))

;; check if set1 is equal to set2
(define (set-equal? set1 set2)
    (and (= (length set1) (length set2))
         (set-contained? set1 set2)))

;; check if x1 is equal to x2, when x1 and x2 can be sets or elements
(define (my-equal? x1 x2)
  (cond ((list? x1) (and (list? x2) (set-equal? x1 x2)))
        ((list? x2) false)
        (else (eq? x1 x2))))

;; add the element x to set, if not already present 
(define (add-to-set x set)
  (cond ((null? set) (list x))
        ((my-equal? x (car set)) set)
        (else (cons (car set) (add-to-set x (cdr set))))))

;; make a set from a list lst
(define (make-set lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((list? (car lst)) (add-to-set (make-set (car lst)) (make-set (cdr lst))))
        (else (add-to-set (car lst) (make-set (cdr lst))))))

(make-set (list 1 2 3 2 (list 1 3 2 4 3 4) (list 1 3 2 4 3 4)))  ; => '(1 3 (1 2 3 4) 2)
```

The function `make-set` builds the set by inserting in turn each element of the original list in a new set, so to check if the element is already present (also, if the element is a list, first it is transformed in a set). The other functions should be easy to understand, given the following convention:

1. If a parameter is called `set`, the function expects a list which has been already represented as set.
2. If a parameter is called `x`, then it is either a number or a set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of `make-set` is a little unclear, but maybe this works for you:

```
(define make-set
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst)                            '())
          ((list? (car lst))                      (cons (make-set (car lst)) (make-set (cdr lst))))
          ((element-of-set? (car lst) (cdr lst))                             (make-set (cdr lst)))
          (else                                   (cons (car lst)            (make-set (cdr lst)))))))
```

Note that using `lst` is not in common use.

A nice convention is to use `x` as an element in a list and use `xs` as a list of x-elements.

Comment: Yes, in many fixed fonts `1st` and `lst` look similar (and unlike in many languages, in Racket and Scheme `1st` is a valid identifier name).

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it doesn't seem to work like I want too. (make-set (list 1 2 3 2 (list 1 2 3 2 4 4) 2 (list 1 2 3 2 4 4))) gives me '(1 3 (1 2 3 2 4 4) 2 (1 2 3 2 4 4)) but I want it to give me '(1 3 (1 2 3 4) 2) in this particular case. So if a list is an element then I want it to delete every duplicated element in that particular list also (and notice if two lists with the exact same elements appear twice, with the exact same elements, one of the lists should be deleted). Sorry if I was a little unclear, hope you understand it better now, otherwise let me know.

Comment: @simpan I have updates the solution. The `(list? (car lst))` clause now calls `make-set`.

Comment: Note that, even modified, the function does not solve the OP, since it returns `'(1 3 2 (1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4))` instead of `'(1 3 2 (1 2 3 4))`, as it is requested.

Comment: I still haven't figured out, what the OP wanted.